# Rendering 10M point that changing position (individualy) at 30Hz

Tags: rendering

i'm able with openTk (vb.net) to draw 10M of points adn rendering it.

The problem is that the bind operation take 114mS on every frame refresh.

I need to refresh the position at 30 Hz , so what can i use for speeder this operation.

Comment: Can you tell us anything about the logic by which these points change position? We might be able to move that logic to the GPU, so you don't have to bind and upload new position information from the CPU each frame.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past ([Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-JoAqO2ofg) 5 million particles morphing from one sphere layout to another...) but to achieve that I needed  to move all the calculations to the GPU. In my case, I achieved that using a compute shader. Fundamentally you need to reduce the communication between CPU and GPU to the absolute minimum for each frame, so what information do you actually need to animate these particles? And can that same info be applied to all particles? eg new focus point/wind direction/whatever that the GPU can apply to all particles?